# How can I do conditional authorization on a column basis?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016+
There is a need to authorize some fields on the basis of userId.

Users operate on the same record on the screen. I run the same procedure in all cases.

I am getting the userId and roleId of the user. From the value of the roleId I know which records it should actually update.

For example, if role=0, it can update all columns, but if role=2, only dataField1 and dataField2 can be updated. If @role=3 it can update the dataField1,dataField3,dataField4 field.

I thought of making 3 update statements with if, is there a more efficient solution?

I have a table called "rolePrivileges". In this table, I keep the information in 2 columns as roleId, roleFields. (I can modify this table.I can't use it right now.)

If I do it with if in the procedure, I will have to update my procedure when the user changes privileges.

How can I do the most effective column authorization on a per user basis without updating the procedure (without changing the database)?

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dataField1] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [dataField2] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [dataField3] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [dataField4] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [userId] [int] NULL,
    [recTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [recUniq] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_myTable_recTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [recTime]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_myTable_recUniq]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [recUniq]
```

```
create PROCEDURE myTableProcedure 
     @id int=0
    ,@dataField1 varchar(10) = '' 
    ,@dataField2 varchar(10) = ''
    ,@dataField3 varchar(10) = ''
    ,@dataField4 varchar(10) = ''
    ,@userId int=0
    ,@role tinyint=0 --1=All Column, 2=dataField1,dataField2, 3=dataField1,dataField3,dataField4 (not=2)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --New Record
    if (@id=0)
    Begin
    insert into myTable (dataField1,dataField2,dataField3,dataField4,userId) values (@dataField1,@dataField2,@dataField3,@dataField4,@userId)
    End 
    --Updated
    else
    Begin
        update myTable set
             dataField1=@dataField1
            ,dataField2=@dataField2
            ,dataField3=@dataField3
            ,dataField4=@dataField4
        where id=@id
    End
END
```

```
--role=1 insert
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=0
    ,@dataField1= 'A' 
    ,@dataField2= 'B'
    ,@dataField3= 'C'
    ,@dataField4= 'D'
    ,@userId=789
    ,@role=1
--role=2 insert
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=0
    ,@dataField1= 'A' 
    ,@dataField2= 'B'
    ,@dataField3= 'C'
    ,@dataField4= 'D'
    ,@userId=123
    ,@role=2
--role=3 insert
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=0
    ,@dataField1= 'A' 
    ,@dataField2= 'B'
    ,@dataField3= 'C'
    ,@dataField4= 'D'
    ,@userId=456
    ,@role=3
```

```
select * from myTable
```

| id | dataField1 | dataField2 | dataField3 | dataField4 | userId | recTime | recUniq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | D | 789 | 2022-10-19 14:55:25.123 | 617ab880-6c35-49da-933a-a67f7efd269b |
| 2 | A | B | C | D | 123 | 2022-10-19 14:55:25.123 | 78e9370c-99ee-486c-b816-16ead2b67850 |
| 3 | A | B | C | D | 456 | 2022-10-19 14:55:25.123 | 72a9850e-ec27-4950-96ef-cd0cb11694c5 |

```
--role=1 insert
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=1
    ,@dataField1= 'E' 
    ,@dataField2= 'F'
    ,@dataField3= 'G'
    ,@dataField4= 'H'
    ,@userId=789
    ,@role=1
--role=2 insert
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=2
    ,@dataField1= 'E' 
    ,@dataField2= 'F'
    ,@dataField3= 'G'
    ,@dataField4= 'H'
    ,@userId=123
    ,@role=2
--role=3 insert
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=3
    ,@dataField1= 'E' 
    ,@dataField2= 'F'
    ,@dataField3= 'G'
    ,@dataField4= 'H'
    ,@userId=456
    ,@role=3
```

```
select * from myTable
```

| id | dataField1 | dataField2 | dataField3 | dataField4 | userId | recTime | recUniq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | E | F | G | H | 789 | 2022-10-19 14:55:25.123 | 617ab880-6c35-49da-933a-a67f7efd269b |
| 2 | E | F | G | H | 123 | 2022-10-19 14:55:25.123 | 78e9370c-99ee-486c-b816-16ead2b67850 |
| 3 | E | F | G | H | 456 | 2022-10-19 14:55:25.123 | 72a9850e-ec27-4950-96ef-cd0cb11694c5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tRNaxuVa)

Comment: If the domain name exists in the authorization table, update it. Could it be something like 
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/665LUikO)

Comment: Is there a reason regular permissions do not work for you?

Comment: @SeanGallardy I get error message with "Column Level Permissions". User @role=2 can insert, select, delete dataField1,dataField2 field. But I don't want it to update. I can do this with if like in the link. But as the number of users and domains increases, it becomes difficult for me to manage. fiddle

Comment: That's what groups were made to do along with database level roles.

Comment: My goal is to make it work without changing the update string in the procedure. It gives the following error when it wants to update the non-permitted fields. My aim update other fields without an error message. "Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure myTableProcedure, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 4]
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'myTableProcedure', database 'test', schema 'dbo'."

Comment: That's not an error due to the update, that's a permissions error - give them execute permissions. Also, silently truncating and not updating data is not a good thing.

Answer (score -1):

I think option 1 from this article might help (column level permissions):
https://satoricyber.com/sql-server-security/sql-server-column-level-security/

Also, you can think of creating views and granting access to those views instead of the columns.

Comment: I get error message with "Column Level Permissions". User @role=2 can insert, select, delete dataField1,dataField2 field. But I don't want it to update.

I can do this with if like in the link. But as the number of users and domains increases, it becomes difficult for me to manage.   [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VmudtS2l)