# Creating a variable procedure statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an procedure statement as below. My update sentence changes according to the @role parameter here.

Is it possible to dynamically make the sentence in the procedure according to the "rolePrivileges" table?

[image: rolePrivileges]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dataField1] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [dataField2] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [dataField3] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [dataField4] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [userId] [int] NULL,
    [recTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [recUniq] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_myTable_recTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [recTime]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_myTable_recUniq]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [recUniq]
```

```
create PROCEDURE myTableProcedure 
     @id int=0
    ,@dataField1 varchar(10) = '' 
    ,@dataField2 varchar(10) = ''
    ,@dataField3 varchar(10) = ''
    ,@dataField4 varchar(10) = ''
    ,@userId int=0
    ,@role tinyint=0 --1=All Column, 2=dataField1,dataField2, 3=dataField1,dataField3,dataField4 (not=2)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --New Record
    if (@id=0)
    Begin
    insert into myTable (dataField1,dataField2,dataField3,dataField4,userId) values (@dataField1,@dataField2,@dataField3,@dataField4,@userId)
    End 
    --Updated
    else
    Begin
---------------------------- Variable partition based on @role value.
        if (@role=1)
        begin
            update myTable set
                 dataField1=@dataField1
                ,dataField2=@dataField2
                ,dataField3=@dataField3
                ,dataField4=@dataField4
                ,recTime=getdate()
            where id=@id
        end
        else if (@role=2)
        begin
            update myTable set
                 dataField1=@dataField1
                ,dataField2=@dataField2
                --,dataField3=@dataField3
                --,dataField4=@dataField4
                ,recTime=getdate()
            where id=@id
        end
        else if (@role=3)
        begin
            update myTable set
                 dataField1=@dataField1
                --,dataField2=@dataField2
                ,dataField3=@dataField3
                ,dataField4=@dataField4
                ,recTime=getdate()
            where id=@id
        end
---------------------------- Variable partition based on @role value./
    End
END
```

```
--role=1 insert
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=0
    ,@dataField1= 'A' 
    ,@dataField2= 'B'
    ,@dataField3= 'C'
    ,@dataField4= 'D'
    ,@userId=789
    ,@role=1
--role=2 insert
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=0
    ,@dataField1= 'A' 
    ,@dataField2= 'B'
    ,@dataField3= 'C'
    ,@dataField4= 'D'
    ,@userId=123
    ,@role=2
--role=3 insert
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=0
    ,@dataField1= 'A' 
    ,@dataField2= 'B'
    ,@dataField3= 'C'
    ,@dataField4= 'D'
    ,@userId=456
    ,@role=3
```

```
select * from myTable
```

| id | dataField1 | dataField2 | dataField3 | dataField4 | userId | recTime | recUniq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | D | 789 | 2022-10-25 13:22:28.380 | 63e3356b-0a28-4de5-9441-c7be13cd03b3 |
| 2 | A | B | C | D | 123 | 2022-10-25 13:22:28.380 | 657e8971-a6a3-4ab2-9849-ee7060324565 |
| 3 | A | B | C | D | 456 | 2022-10-25 13:22:28.380 | b1f2e13d-bcc3-4e76-b6a8-05c3a43da619 |

```
--role=1 update
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=1
    ,@dataField1= '11' 
    ,@dataField2= '11'
    ,@dataField3= '11'
    ,@dataField4= '11'
    ,@userId=789
    ,@role=1
--role=2 update
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=2
    ,@dataField1= '22' 
    ,@dataField2= '22'
    ,@dataField3= '22'
    ,@dataField4= '22'
    ,@userId=123
    ,@role=2
--role=3 update
execute myTableProcedure 
     @id=3
    ,@dataField1= '33' 
    ,@dataField2= '33'
    ,@dataField3= '33'
    ,@dataField4= '33'
    ,@userId=456
    ,@role=3
```

```
select * from myTable
```

| id | dataField1 | dataField2 | dataField3 | dataField4 | userId | recTime | recUniq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 11 | 11 | 11 | 789 | 2022-10-25 13:22:28.380 | 63e3356b-0a28-4de5-9441-c7be13cd03b3 |
| 2 | 22 | 22 | C | D | 123 | 2022-10-25 13:22:28.393 | 657e8971-a6a3-4ab2-9849-ee7060324565 |
| 3 | 33 | B | 33 | 33 | 456 | 2022-10-25 13:22:28.393 | b1f2e13d-bcc3-4e76-b6a8-05c3a43da619 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Z2aWCiZ)

Comment: I'm going to go with a big no on this design - can you highlight exactly what you're trying to do and we can start there? Also, create a new question asking the same thing as your old question https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/318413/212533

Comment: The question is not the same. This question is about whether the sentence in the transaction can be dynamic.  The other question is about column-based authorization.

Comment: Then please explain more clearly exactly what you want to achieve. You want to dynamically create and execute the `update` statement? What have you tried so far? And why does it need to be dynamic anyway?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes. I want to dynamically generate and execute the update statement.  This is how I dynamically created the sentence from the table.  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vVpJd6_d) But how do I put it in the procedure. I do not know.

Comment: If you're passively dropping data, it's not going to go well. This is a terrible design that will in fact lose data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what issue you are having with executing a dynamic statement, but this is roughy how you would do it.

Just use a bunch of `CASE` expressions to build up the statement dynamically. Then pass the parameters in using `sp_executesql`. Do *not* inject the data directly into the dynamic part.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE myTableProcedure 
     @id int=0
    ,@dataField1 varchar(10) = '' 
    ,@dataField2 varchar(10) = ''
    ,@dataField3 varchar(10) = ''
    ,@dataField4 varchar(10) = ''
    ,@userId int=0
    ,@role tinyint=0 --1=All Column, 2=dataField1,dataField2, 3=dataField1,dataField3,dataField4 (not=2)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (@id = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT myTable (dataField1, dataField2, dataField3, dataField4, userId)
    VALUES (@dataField1, @dataField2, @dataField3, @dataField4, @userId);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = CONCAT('
update myTable
set
  dataField1 = @dataField1
  ,',
      CASE WHEN @role IN (1, 2) THEN 'dataField2 = @dataField2
  ,' END,
      CASE WHEN @role IN (1, 3) THEN 'dataField3 = @dataField3
  ,dataField4 = @dataField4
  ,' END,
      'recTime = getdate()
where id = @id;
'
    );

    PRINT @sql;     -- your friend

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
      N'@id int ,@dataField1 varchar(10), @dataField2 varchar(10), @dataField3 varchar(10), @dataField4 varchar(10), @userId int',
     @id = @id
    ,@dataField1 = @dataField1
    ,@dataField2 = @dataField2
    ,@dataField3 = @dataField3
    ,@dataField4 = @dataField4
    ,@userId = @userId;
END;
```

Comment: Got what I wanted with a little update. Thank you. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OKnqG8KO)